# How to make an icon spin in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a spinning icon through React and I think there's something I'm missing in my attempt. Here's my return function.

```
  return (
    <div className="loader">
      <p>Loading Data</p>
      <FaIcons.FaCog className="loaderIcon"/>
    </div>
  );
```

And here's the CSS.

```
.loaderIcon .spin.FaIcons{
    margin-right: 7px;
    top: 2px;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the icon isn't spinning?

Comment: Probably the selector doesn't match the HTML, double check in your dev tools

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was that I was referencing the wrong class. I only had to reference the icon class.

```
.loaderIcon {
    margin-right: 7px;
    top: 2px;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector you are using, `.loaderIcon .spin.FaIcons`, is very specific. If you want the element rendered from the `FaIcons.FaCog` to spin, change your selector to `.loaderIcon, .spin.FaIcons`. There is a comma inserted, turning this into a selector *list*, instead of a single selector.

E.g. `.loaderIcon` AND `.spin.FaIcons`, instead of `.loaderIcon .spin.FaIcons`;

This is more of a CSS issue than React, so it applies in other web apps as well.